# What does $1, $2, etc. mean in Regular Expressions?

Tags: javascript

Time and time again I see $1 and $2 being used in code. What does it mean? Can you please include examples?

Comment: This may be helpful to you: [Grouping & Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Comment: Similar question: [How to explain “$1,$2” in Javascript when using regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702924/how-to-explain-1-2-in-javascript-when-using-regular-expression)

Comment: In above question, I've found answers from "Niels Keurentjes" and "Mark Chorley" easy to understand for new users of JS

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When you create a regular expression you have the option of capturing portions of the match and saving them as placeholders. They are numbered starting at `$1`.

For instance:

```
/A(\d+)B(\d+)C/
```

This will capture from `A90B3C` the values `90` and `3`. If you need to group things but don't want to capture them, use the `(?:...)` version instead of `(...)`.

The numbers start from left to right in the order the brackets are open. That means:

```
/A((\d+)B)(\d+)C/
```

Matching against the same string will capture `90B`, `90` and `3`.

Comment: It would in Perl, but I don't think Ruby supports that kind of back-tracking.

Comment: This is the best explanation,

Comment: This is better than other explanations I could find, but it's still missing an example of actually using $1, $2, etc.

Comment: @Steve You just put those in the substitution string. It's all in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n).

Answer (score 9):

This is esp. useful for [Replacement String Syntax](http://manual.macromates.com/en/regular_expressions) (i.e. Format Strings) Goes good for Cases/Case Foldings for Find & Replaces. To reference a capture, use $n where n is the capture register number. Using $0 means the entire match. Example :  `Find: (<a.*?>)(.*?)(</a>) Replace: $1\u$2\e$3`