# How to explain "$1,$2" in JavaScript when using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

A piece of JavaScript code is as follows:

```
num = "11222333";
re = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
re.test(num);
num.replace(re, "$1,$2");
```

I could not understand the grammar of `"$1,$2"`. The book from which this code comes says `$1` means `RegExp.$1`, `$2` means `RegExp.$2`. But these explanations lead to more questions:

1. It is known that in JavaScript, the name of variables should begin with letter or _, how can `$1` be a valid name of member variable of RegExp here?
2. If I input `$1`, the command line says it is not defined; if I input `"$1"`, the command line only echoes `$1`, not 11222. So, how does the replace method know what `"$1,$2"` mean?

Thank you.

Comment: When it doubt, [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter): "The replacement string can include the following special replacement patterns .." (`$1` is a `$n` replacement pattern). Also see [string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) - JavaScript has no "interpolation" as found in PHP or Perl.

Comment: could you please tell me what "interpolation" mean here?

Comment: In a language with interpolation, `$name = "Fred"; print "Hello $name!"` might result in "Hello Fred!". One text-book definition of interpolation is to "Insert (something) between fixed points" and in computer languages this often means "Insert value of a variable/expression into a string". *JavaScript does not have this feature.* Because this is not present in JavaScript it can be concluded that `"$1,$2"` results in a string of 5 characters and does not interpolate values from any variables - the special handling is then from the `String.replace` function (which I also linked).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's not a "variable" - it's a placeholder that is used in the `.replace()` call. `$n` represents the `nth` capture group of the regular expression.

```js
var num = "11222333";

// This regex captures the last 3 digits as capture group #2
// and all preceding digits as capture group #1
var re = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

console.log(re.test(num));

// This replace call replaces the match of the regex (which happens
// to match everything) with the first capture group ($1) followed by
// a comma, followed by the second capture group ($2)
console.log(num.replace(re, "$1,$2"));
```

Comment: Thank you. but what about my question (1), RegExt.$1? When I input RegExp.$1, the command line returns 11222. So $1 seems to be a member variable of object RegExt. How could $1 be a name of a variable?

Comment: @user2384994: If you mean you replaced the replace pattern with `RegExp.$1`, then it should return `RegExp.11222`. As far as it goes, though, JavaScript variables **can** start with `$`. That's all there is to it.

Comment: In JavaScript, how can be `$1` used in replacement string when it is followed by number (e.g. `0`)? Syntax `$10` is wrong. Please advise.

Answer (score 7):

$1 is the first group from your regular expression, $2 is the second. Groups are defined by brackets, so your first group ($1) is whatever is matched by (\d+). You'll need to do some reading up on regular expressions to understand what that matches.

> It is known that in Javascript, the name of variables should begin with letter or _, how can $1 be a valid name of member variable of RegExp here?

This isn't true. $ is a valid variable name as is $1. You can find this out just by trying it. See jQuery and numerous other frameworks.

Comment: In "..Groups are defined by brackets..." you meant parenthesis ?

Comment: @vikramvi the ( ) brackets (commonly known as Function Brackets) are called parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

You are misinterpreting that line of code. You should consider the string `"$1,$2"` a **format specifier** that is used internally by the `replace` function to know what to do. It uses the previously tested regular expression, which yielded 2 results (two parenthesized blocks), and reformats the results. `$1` refers to the first match, `$2` to the second one. The expected contents of the `num` string is thus `11222,333` after this bit of code.

Answer (score 2):

> It is known that in Javascript, the name of variables should begin with letter or _,

No, it's not. `$1` is a perfectly valid variable. You have to assign to it first though:

```
$variable = "this is a test"
```

This is how jQuery users a variable called `$` as an alias for the `jQuery` object.

Answer (score 2):

> The book from which this code comes says $1 means RegExp.$1, $2 means RegExp.$2.

This book is made of paper. And paper cannot oppose any resistance to whom is writing on it ***:-)*** . But perhaps did you only misinterpret what is actually written in this book.

Actually, it is depending on the context.

1. In the context of the `replace()` *method* of `String`, `$1`, `$2`, ... `$99` (1 through 99) are **placeholders**. They are handled **internally** by the `replace()` *method* (and they have nothing to do with `RegExp.$1`, `RegExp.$2`, etc, which are probably not even defined (see point **2.** )). See [**String.prototype.replace()** #Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter). Compare this with the *return value* of the [`match()` *method* of `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Description) when the *flag* `g` is not used, which is similar to the *return value* of the [`exec()` *method* of `RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description). Compare also with [the arguments passed **implicitly** to an (optional) function specified as second argument of `replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).
2. `RegExp.$1`, `RegExp.$2`, ... `RegExp.$9` (1 through 9 only) are **non-standard** *properties* of `RegExp` as you may see at [RegExp.$1-$9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/n) and [Deprecated and obsolete features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_properties). They seem to be implemented on your browser, but, for somebody else, **they could be not defined**. To use them, you need always to prepend `$1`, `$2`, etc with `RegExp.`. These *properties* are static, read-only and stored in the `RegExp` *global object*, not in an individual regular expression object. But, anyway, ***you should not use them***. The `$1` through `$99` used internally by the `replace()` *method* of `String` are stored **elsewhere**.

Have a nice day!