# Not highlighting first letter of the word in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/drzoLkLw/) is the fiddle in which the search is working fine but its not highlighting the first letter of the text in name column and highlighting remaining matched letters... what is the problem..... and can anyone fix it.......
For example if we type "v" in search bar its showing all the v's but the "v" in the name column its not highlighting..... except the first letter of text in name column every matched element is highlighting

we have to change in this code......

```js
$("#search").keyup(function(){
        _this = $(this);
        var searched_term = $(_this).val().toLowerCase();
  if(_this.val() == ""){
   $.each($("#ftz-table tbody tr td:nth-child(n+2)"), function() { 
   $(this).text($(this).text()); 
  })
  return;
  }
        $.each($("#ftz-table tbody tr td:nth-child(n+2)"), function() {
   var original_text = $(this).text();       
   if(!($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searched_term) == -1)){
    $(this).html(original_text.replace(searched_term, "<mark>"+searched_term+"</mark>"));
   } 
   else{
    $(this).text($(this).text()); 
   }
        });
    });
```

Comment: did not understand your issue. Please rephrase

Comment: Deleted previous question and posted duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Your search is case insensitive but `original_text.replace()` is not, so `indexOf` finds `v` or `V` but `replace` only replaces the one that matches the search input case.

To preserve the case you need a capture:

```
var re = new RegExp("(" + searched_term + ")", "i");
$.each($("#ftz-table tbody tr td:nth-child(n+2)"), function() {
   $(this).html($(this).text().replace(re, "<mark>$1</mark>"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xr0hns13/1/

(`searched_term` should be escaped for any RegExp reserved chars)

Comment: $1 is translated to the value the regex captures - what is inside the parentheses - in the correct case. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702924/how-to-explain-1-2-in-javascript-when-using-regular-expression