# Wrap text in parenthesis in a span tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with some titles in Wordpress. Some titles are episode names and some are article names. The Podcast Episode name titles look like this:

```
<h1>Hello i am a title (EP.11)</h1>
```

Podcast episode titles contain an episode number at the end of the title in a parenthesis. I was hoping to use some jQuery to wrap the parenthesis and its containing text into a `span` tag, like this

```
<h1>
  Hello i am a title 
  <span class="titleEpisodeValue">(EP.11)</span> 
</h1>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

This is a common issue for podcast websites. I hope the specifics of my question attracts similar people. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? any attempt(s) of your own or research?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a regular expression to catch the value within the parenthesis before replacing it with a `span` that contains that text. Something like this:

```js
$('h1').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.replace(/(\(.+\))/g, '<span class="titleEpisodeValue">$1</span>');
});
```

```css
.titleEpisodeValue { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello i am a title (EP.11)</h1>
```

Comment: This works perfectly thanks!

How does the $1 know that that is the content?

Comment: Says i gotta wait more time to award answer.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. The `$1` is the placeholder for matched groups in the Regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702924/how-to-explain-1-2-in-javascript-when-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

```js
var H1=$("h1").html();
var code=H1.substring(H1.indexOf("("), H1.indexOf(")")+1);
$("h1").html(H1.substring(0,H1.indexOf("("))).append($("<span/>",{html:code}));
```

```css
h1 >span{color:pink;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello i am a title (EP.11)</h1>
```