# How to move date to front of string with regex?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Any suggestions of how to use regex to extract a date from the end of a string in YYYY-MM-DD as per ISO ISO861 and move it to the front of the string and replace all hyphens in the preceding string with with commas?

E.g.

“Finland - Tampere, 2019-03-23” -> “2019-03-23, EU, Finland, Tampere”

“US - Virgina - Richmond, 2011-02-29” -> “2011-02-29, US, Virgina, Richmond”

Answer (score 0):

Just create three groups of searches wrapper in () and after this, use '$3 $2 $1' syntax inside replace function, to change order.

Naive implementation for second case:

```
const regex = /(US).*- ([a-zA-Z].*) - ([a-zA-Z]*).*(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/g

const str = 'US - Virgina - Richmond, 2011-02-29';

console.log(str.replace(regex, '$4, $1, $2, $3')) 

// 2011-02-29, US, Virgina, Richmond
```

You can find good explanation of groups [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702924/how-to-explain-1-2-in-javascript-when-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which programming language. There are a number of regex builders online. I link a possible solution which can be tested at regex101.com below.

```
((^(?'COUNTRY'[A-Z]{2})) - )?((?'STATE'([A-Z][a-z]{2,} ?)+) - )((?'CITY'([A-Z][a-z]{2,} ?.*)),).*(?'DATE'(?'YEAR'[0-9]{4})(-(?'MONTH'[0-9]{2})(-(?'DAY'[0-9]{2})))$)
```

This provides named groupings which can be used in code. Since country doesn't appear in both examples, you can provide a default (e.g. EU) through the chosen programming language.

https://regex101.com/r/ls7Eg6/2