# What does '-$1' mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out what the assignment to `id` means in the following snippet, and in particular the `'-$1'`.  I do see that it's taking the DOM element text and swapping in something else, and then lowercasing the result.  I just don't understand what is being swapped in.

```
   for (var k in ui) {
      var id = k.replace(/([A-Z])/, '-$1').toLowerCase();
      var element = document.getElementById(id);
      if (!element) {
        throw "Missing UI element: " + k;
      }
      ui[k] = element;
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter

Comment: Duplicate? [What does $1, $2, etc. mean in Regular Expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5982824/218196)

Comment: Downvotes seem harsh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What does '-$1' mean in javascript?

Nothing. But `$1` in a `replace` replacement string refers to the first capture group, saying "include the first capture group in the replacement here." The `-` is literal text to include in the replacement.

```
var id = k.replace(/([A-Z])/, '-$1').toLowerCase();
// Capture group    ^     ^
```

What that call does is replace the first upper-case letter in the English alphabet (`A-Z`) with a dash followed by the character (and then the `.toLowerCase()` after it turns the string to all lower-case). E.g., "testingABC" becomes "testing-abc". (It's only the first upper-case letter because there's no "global" [`g`] flag on the regular expression.)

In this particular case, the code doesn't need to use a capture group, it could be this:

```
var id = k.replace(/[A-Z]/, '-$&').toLowerCase()
```

`$&` refers to the entire match.

Comment: And how is does the `-` come into play?  It looks like the id naming convention in the .html here is hypen-separated.  E.g. `id="input-panel"`.

Comment: @tarabyte: It's just an arbitrary character.

Comment: @tarabyte: Sorry, I've added a bit to address the `-`. (Felix is -- characteristically -- right, though.)