# How to replace multiple keywords with double quote (" ") in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I need some help. I'm trying to replace multiple keywords in notepad++. See example below:

Find all:

> apple alpha anchor ants all am are

Replace with:

> "apple" "alpha" "anchor" "ants" "all" "am" "are"

Is there a way to replace it in one go?

Comment: Are all keywords only lowercase alphabetic? Or could they contain any character?

Answer (score 1):

Press Hotkey: Ctrl + H (Replace)

tab: Replace

Find what: `((\b[^\s]+\b)((?<=\.\w).)?)`

Replace with: `"$1"`

Select searchmode: Regular expression

Replace all => DONE

**UPDATE**

`((\b[^\s]+\b)((?<=\.\w).)?)` Regular expression, you can find more information in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), some good tutorial is [here](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285) and [here](https://regexone.com/): this regex will select all "word" seperate by `space` or `.`

`"$1"`you can find more information about this symbol [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982824/what-does-1-2-etc-mean-in-regular-expressions), mean we replace each word with `""` and put the selected word it the middle

Comment: Thank you it did work! Can you explain the formula ((\b[^\s]+\b)((?<=\.\w).)?) and "$1"? Thank you so much..

Comment: @ZoeC I did update my answer, for more information, you can visit those link I provided or you can extract keyword and do some google search for your self.

Comment: Why are you using lookbehind? And word boundary?

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\w+`
- Replace with: `"$0"`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\w+ # 1 or more word character (i.e. [a-zA-Z0-9_])
         you could use [a-z]+ instead of \w+ if you want only lowercases
                    or \S+ if you want to match any character that is not a space
```

**Replacement:**

```
"   # a double quote
$0  # content of group 0, the whole match (i.e. the keyword)
"   # a double quote
```

**Result for given example:**

```
"apple" "alpha" "anchor" "ants" "all" "am" "are"
```